# Can someone identify this tree in Playa Del Carmen, Quintana Roo, Mexico?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I just noticed this tree in Playa del Carmen in Yucatan. It was swarming with bats, the bat seem to be eating either the fruit or the flowers of the tree. Any idea what it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide approximate sizes of the leaves, fruit, and tree as a whole. Mentioning more specifics about the location (e.g., did you find the tree along the road, in town, in a wooded area, etc.) would be helpful. Finally, updating your post with clearer photos (of leaves, bark, and fruit) would all be ideal and likely would result in a more accurate ID. Thanks

Comment: You might also check out [101 YUCATAN TREES](https://www.backyardnature.net/yucatan/101/index.htm) (Conrad, 2015) for a site with some decent photos and data for trees of the Yucatan.

Comment: This looks more like a fig tree...

Answer (score -1):

The photos are blurred. We need a pic of the bark and of the fruit, sliced. Does it have pips or a nut? Perhaps a Palaquium variety, i.e.  [Palaquium Gutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaquium_gutta), which is for producing latex/rubber, because it's in a garden and its a useful commodity plant previously grown in south america. Perhaps slice and study the fruit for a better ID. [image]

Latex plants attract bats.
You can check the bark for latex.
https://youtu.be/6DJHD91VKKY

Comment: your proposed species is native to Malaysia! (not Mexico). Actually, the entire Genus is native to Southeast Asia / Oceania (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaquium)). What makes you think this is correct? Please update your answer with more convincing information. Thanks!

Comment: I'm quite aware of that! Corn is native to the US and quite a few million hectares are found in Eurasia. Cultivacion y laminado de caucho natural! https://youtu.be/6DJHD91VKKY besides i'm not certain, it's just a lead, he can check the bark. Otherwise its perhaps related to avocado. He has to check the fruit. We can't guess much from the blurry photos.

Comment: My guess is as good as the photos, which are not very accurate. the info fits though, quote: Palaquium gutta — The ripe fruit, but not the seeds, is eaten by fruit bats. ... its growing in a garden beside a wall, we commonly see many non native plants in gardens and cities.

Comment: Understandable. My concern is that many users and visitors coming through our site just look for whatever is written as answers and often don't think in terms of "this is a guess based on low quality starting info". As such, someone (including the OP) might just assume you're giving the "right answer". I think we all need to be very clear and explicit when we're guessing. I don't think you make that clear on the post, so please edit to clarify. I would suggest adding some additional context based on your comments.

Comment: Something like "based on your low quality photos, I'd guess it's ___ because ___. Although it's not native, ___ are some reasons I still think it's possible. You could check the bark or other characteristics to be certain. Perhaps you could investigate related species in your area. I'd recommend starting your investigation with species related to avacado because ___" something in that style let's us see inside your head and whatever expertise or research you bring to the table without judging your response to be definitive and allows a jumping off point for the OP. Please consider editing. Thx

Comment: The photos are blurry, the fruit isn't photod, neither is the bark, nor the petiole angles along the branches. It's perhaps a correct ID, and it taught me about plant latexes, and encourages proper identification of plants using bark, and fruit dissection. People identify non-native plants in gardens very regularly on Stack, I get 95 of my species ID's correct. so at least i tried. 95% is not bad. so i will leave the answer and Ill ask a colleague with zoology and botany degrees from Cambridge who works in the Amazon rainforest.

Comment: It's funny cos my dad was a forest ecology lecturer at oxford for about 46 years and i'm just randomly ID'ing stuff which is hard to ID and not even getting it, and then a forest ecologist is telling me off. That's the actual title of my dad's job "Forest Ecology tutor" but he is a prof at humanities and human ecology not forestry which was just a BSc. Wee-ird.

Comment: 1. I'm not telling you off. I'm asking you to provide more detailed support and to be explicit + clear about how you got to your answer and how others should interpret and use your info. 2.There's no reliable method for judging ID accuracy here, so I'm not sure how you got 95%. 3. It doesn't matter who you/your acquaintances are or what any of you know -- your post should be detailed, explicit, and cited. See [meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4129). 4. I'd advise not answering unclear ID posts unless they're edited. 5. [Watch the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232)

Comment: not a fan of stentors thanks. chill out it's an adult website and i'm 42 not 2. the marking system is there for a reason. The OP isn't interested enough in this page to post more precise information therefore this ID is not likely.

Comment: If the ID photos are not updated with bark photos and fruit photos, it doesn't do justice to the people who volunteer to ID it, so if there is a problem with this page, it's the lack of flowers/fruit/bark photos essential for me to  update the post.

Comment: Right, that's why I advised not answering unclear posts. If the OP won't/can't update with clearer photos or more detail, then the best answer anyone can give is more likely not accurate (because IDing something is HARD if it's not clear what you're IDing!). Ask the OP to clarify, vote to close, and move on. If you think guessing or adding a formalized line of thinking would be useful to others, then by all means provide an answer. However, make it clear that your answer is approximating some species based on XYZ characteristics. You've taken this approach, but I'm asking you to expand/clarify